# What does this PHP namespace code block mean?

Tags: php, namespaces

I currently encountered this namespace code block during code review that I looks something like this. I'm new to namespaces and examples I've seen in youtube and tutorials have no similar example.

I only understand the first namespace means the code block will be on global space. But what does the second namespace exactly mean?

```
namespace
{
     class Logging{} 
}

namespace Admin\Logging
{
      class Logged_in
      {
          public function __construct()
          {
                /* some code here */
          }
      }

      /* other classes here */
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest you read over the Namespaces section of the PHP Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: Did that already before posting here but most examples explained there  have name appended after namespace or not similar to the namespace structure I encountered... thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

The second declaration is a [sub namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nested.php) or nested namespace.

In your example, the class `Logged_in` would have the canonical name of `\Admin\Logging\Logged_in`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know how to use it... I'm just having a hard time converting Admin\Logging in layman's term so I can further understand their connection... Apologies for not being clear with my question.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for namespaces is similar to directory hierarchy: backslashes (`\`) act as separators for subnamespaces.

Therefore the second notation indicates the definition of the `Admin` namespace, and of the `Logging` namespace within it.

See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, hope I got this right...

In layman's term, Admin\Logging means "where can I find this file"

```
|--admin
|  |-- Logging.php
```

and that

```
namespace
{
    class Logging {}
}
```

because both namespace are in the same file, it can serve as a library and be autoloaded...

Wew... I'm not really technical but that's how I understand it..... thanks all for your help.

Thanks to: http://www.mwop.net/blog/254-Why-PHP-Namespaces-Matter.html